Both elements are running in my hot water tank and it keeps over heating
We recently had an incident where one element in the hot water heater cracked open and then grounded causing our house power to shut down at the main outside breaker. My dad tested the electrical current and also determined that we had power constantly going to the bottom element and switch from the top element. We decided to buy 2 new elements and 2 new switches. After installation we tested the switches and found that when the top switch ran the bottom was off and when the water was heated that the bottom one would get turned on. After 5 days our water heater tripped and we found out that the tripping happened because the water was over heated. We adjusted the temp and within a day it happened again and the hot water heater tripped again. We tested the elements, testing when the top element would turn on and off and found that again it was sending power to the bottom switch while the top switch was running. I'm guessing that means the bottom one is always running and also means the thermostat isn't working at least on the bottom one, possibly top. It tripped again this morning. Do we replace parts or do you think there is other damage that will continue to be a problem and should the bottom element get power when the top element is running?

Replacing parts without testing them can get expensive.  I would test the thermostat first, since that is the part that should control the elements.  I would also reread the wiring diagram to check the wires are correct.

An electric tank water heater is actually a pretty clever device. See this Technology Connections video for a complete explanation. But the bottom line is that only one element should be running at any time. If both are running then something is wired incorrectly or (since it used to work OK) broken.
I don't think the problem is the elements, and you replaced them anyway. The problem is in the controls/switches that are supposed to turn on one - and only one - element at a time.
I would first look at the age of the water heater. If it is more than 12 years old, or if there are any signs of leaking or corrosion, cut your losses and replace it now.
If it is newer and there are no signs of problems with the tank then it is a matter of replacing the other electrical components. There really shouldn't be a whole lot more to it, but the specifics will depend on the particular make/model.

Rather than replacing parts, find out what's wrong with your wiring.  The elements should turn off when the thermostat stops calling for heat, and turning one element on shouldn't cause the other to be permanently on too.
